# Flutter Firebase FieldValue IncrementCounter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, increment

My question is: I am working with client orders in my Flutter App. If a customer placing an order, I want to set the number 1, the next order would be 2 and so on...if I delete orders, I want to go always forward ++ for all new documents(orders). I have created a field OrderNr. in the document. And I have at the moment a variable with a value 0. But when I am placing an order it always gets 1 and doesn't go forward. As I understand, if App starts, it has to check all documents(orders) and their fields OrderNr., then identify the highest number and if next document will be created the variable should get an increment.
How could I do it?

Code snippet of creating a collection Requests with their documents:

```
final DocumentReference
                                        documentReference = await Firestore
                                            .instance
                                            .collection('Requests')
                                            .add({'DocID': ""});
                                    final String docIDD =
                                        documentReference.documentID;
                                    Map<String, dynamic> data = {
                                      "Anfrage vom":
                                          _currentDateToday.toString(),
                                      "Anschluss Herd": isSwitchedHerd,
                                      "Anschluss WaMa": isSwitchedWasch,
                                      "Anschluss Spuel": isSwitchedSpuel,
                                      "Hängeschränke": isSwitchedHaenge,
                                      "Gebrauchte Küche": isSwitchedAlt,
                                      "Arbeitsplatte bearbeiten":
                                          isSwitchedPlatte,
                                      "Küchenlaenge":
                                          _kuechenlaengeController.text,
                                      "Name": _nameController.text,
                                      "Email": _emailController.text,
                                      "Telefon": _phoneController.text,
                                      "Anschrift": _anschrift.text,
                                      "Kommentar Kunde":
                                          _kommentarController.text,
                                      "Gesamt geschätzt": grandTotal,
                                      "Administrator Anmerkung": '...',
                                      "Wunschdatum": currentDate.toString(),
                                      "Document ID": docIDD,
                                      "AuftragNr": auftragNr,
                                    };
                                    Firestore.instance
                                        .collection('Requests')
                                        .document(docIDD)
                                        .setData(data);
                                    Navigator.push(context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(builder:
                                            (BuildContext context) {
                                      return AfterRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an ERP based solution, there is control menu where initial value is assigned and the value increases when an order is created.

Maybe you can implement a similar approach, you can have one separate collection with a field order number which have initial order number value say 1, and every time a user will place an order then you return this value as order number and this value will be increased to 2.

Let's say if the order is deleted you will still have the incremented order number in the other collection.

I hope this made sense.

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be a good solution. I will try to implement it. I have just started with programming.